# Java Stored Procedure to IBM i Connection from Oracle Database 11g

Tags: database, oracle11g, ibm-midrange

We are trying to connect DB2 for i Database (formerly known as an AS/400) from a Java Stored Procedure.
We are getting the following message:

> To PL/SQL to grant this is dbms_java.grant_permission('user', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx', 'connect, resolve')

We have done this by:

> exec dbms_java.grant_permission('user', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx', 'connect, resolve');/commit;/

We created an ACL and added Privileges for the User.
But we are still getting the same error.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like an authority problem on the Oracle side, before it even tries to connect to the IBM i system, correct?

Comment: It is solved by removing all duplicate permission in the java$policy Table

Comment: You can post the solution as an Answer to help others who may encounter a problem like this and seek the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution:
1- Remove all duplicate Records in JAVA$POLICY table.
2- Grant the permission for the user on the default Oracle port (1521)

> exec dbms_java.grant_permission('user', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', 'xx.xx.xx.xx:1521', 'connect, resolve');/commit;/